# Ember-Data query for models matching an element in array

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using Ember for a basic blog, and I have the collection of blogs loaded into the store. One of the properties of the model is tags. i.e.

```
post: {
    title: '...',
    post_content: '...',
    tags: [ 'javascript', 'ember' ]
}
```

I've read all of the documentation on the 'find' method in DS.store, but I couldn't find anything on querying models where an element in the array matches the query.

Any one know how you're supposed to do this?

EDIT: Here is my relevant Ember code

TEMPLATE:

```
<ul class="nav nav-stacked">
    {{#each post in controller}}
        {{#link-to 'post' post tagName="li"}}<a href="#post">{{post.title}}</a>{{/link-to}}
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

ROUTE:

```
App.JsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('post');
    }
});
```

CONTROLLER:

```
App.JsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    sortProperties: ['creationDate'],
    sortAscending: true
});
```

I tried doing this for the Route:

```
App.JsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.filter('post', function(record){ 
                    return record.getEach('tags').indexOf('javascript') > 0;
                });
    }
});
```

But I got the following error:

```
Error while loading route: TypeError {} ember.js:417
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getEach'
```

I also added a computed property in my controller that was an array of the collection filtered, which worked, but I'd rather filter the posts via the `model` method in the route. Any help to accomplish this in the route would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my JSON:

```
{ posts:
   [ { __v: 2,
       _id: 1,
       author: '...',
       complete: true,
       creationDate: Sun Nov 17 2013 18:20:00 GMT-0800 (PST),
       post_content: '...',
       title: 'Dissecting JavaScript Objects',
       tags: [ 'javascript', ' objects' ] },
     { __v: 2,
       _id: 2,
       author: '...',
       complete: true,
       creationDate: Wed Nov 20 2013 20:03:27 GMT-0800 (PST),
       post_content: '...',
       title: 'How to create basic chainable functions',
       tags: [ 'underscore', 'objects' ] }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a filtered record set.

**Ember API**

```
  @method filter
  @param {Class} type
  @param {Function} filter
  @return {DS.FilteredRecordArray}
  filter: function(type, query, filter) ....
```

**Example Usage**

```
  this.store.filter('post',
     function(record){ 
       return record.get('tags').contains(model.tag)
     });
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/AkOxamu/1/edit

If you use 2 arguments it will use the second as the filter function.

Additionally filtered records sets are really cool, they are active record sets, so they will be updated as the system finds new records that satisfies the filter.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't really get the first part of your code with the @ items. It looks more like Ruby than Ember. What does that do?

Comment: Sorry, that was the api from the code, the bottom portion that applies to you.

Comment: I've played around with this a little bit. Would that example usage go into the route in the model method?

Comment: yeah, you could return it from the model hook.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to do that, but it didn't work. The only way I could get it to work was by adding a computed property in the controller.

Comment: According to your code above you're calling filter on the collection, not on the store.

Comment: You should be calling it on the store like my example

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I had tried that too (and revised my post), but I got a TypeError that record has not `getEach` method.

Comment: do you mind posting an example of your json and I'll build up an example of how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help! I added the JSON that I'm working with. The route near the top of my posts works to get all of the documents, but I have tried a million different things to get the filter to work.

Comment: There ya go, I kind of shoved together an ugly example, but it shows how to use the filter.

Comment: That did the trick! I had my route a little different, but how you implemented is making me rethink how I set it up. Thanks!

Comment: I believe this post is talking about an ember data addon: https://github.com/ember-data/ember-data-filter

Comment: With newer versions of emberjs, that's correct. Back when this answer was written, `filter` was part of ember data binary (you can see it in the jsbin).